# Can't get soundcloud access_token using php sdk. invalid_grant error

Tags: php, zend-framework, oauth-2.0, access-token, soundcloud

I am using soundcloud php sdk. It works successfully when i use the sdk to get track. But when i've tried to get an access Token in order to use it, the sdk send me back an error 401. After debugging the error message, i ve get the responseJSON below: {"error":"invalid_grant"}

This is my code , i m using Zend framework

```
$code = $this->getRequest()->getParam('code',false);
if($code){
$client = new Services_Soundcloud($this->soundcloud['client_id'],$this->soundcloud['secret_key']);
try {
$access_token = $client->accessToken($code);
} catch (Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e) {
exit($e->getMessage());
}
}
```

Did anyone has any idea about how to solve this error ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to exchange a code for an access token, you must instantiate your `Services_Soundcloud` instance with a client id, client secret *and* a redirect uri. The following code should work, assuming you are storing the redirect uri in `$this->soundcloud`:

```
$client = new Services_Soundcloud(
    $this->soundcloud['client_id'],
    $this->soundcloud['secret_key'],
    $this->soundcloud['redirect_uri']
);

$code = $this->getRequest()->getParam('code',false);

if ($code) {
    try {
        $access_token = $client->accessToken($code);
    } catch (Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e) {
        exit($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Let me know if that solves the problem.